# Websockets Bundle Dependency on sun.misc

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, grizzly

I am attempting to create a Websockets- based application using the Grizzly Websockets bundles. I am doing this in Apache Felix using Bndtools.

Unfortunately, I seem to have all the needed dependencies, but the Grizzly bundles are failing to load due to the following failure:

```
org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets-server-2.3.23Unable to resolve 
org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets-server [23](R 23.0): missing 
requirement [org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets-server [23](R 23.0)] 
osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=sun.misc) Unresolved 
requirements: [[org.glassfish.grizzly.websockets-server [23](R 23.0)] 
osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=sun.misc)]
```

I have researched this failure, originally looking for a bundle, only to discover that apparently this is some kind of JVM library that is really not needed. I have seen workarounds and solutions that involve adding a line to a conf/config.properties file:

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=sun.misc
```

I understand that this is a dangerous workaround, and there are rumors of "safer" solutions to this problem. They all involve making changes to  tags or to the config.properties file.

Unfortunately, in a Bndtools environment, there are apparently no such tags or files for me to edit!

Or, at least, I cannot find these things in my Bndtools project.

Is there some way to fix this "sun.misc" problem within a Bndtools- based project? I am using Bndtools repository and am wondering which of the various "bnd" files I need to edit, as well as what to put into those files.

Someone please advise...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `-runsystempackages: sun.misc` to the bnd/bndrun file.

Comment: Apparently, for this version of Felix (5.2), adding the runproperties line described in the answer above does not work. this runsystempackages line does...

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for that is https://github.com/diffplug/osgiX

You just will change PKG=sun.misc(or another package) in gradle.properties and run gradlew build.

It will generate bundle-fragment, which you will can add to your class path.
The bundle then contains:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: sun.misc
Fragment-Host: system.bundle; extension:=framework
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-License: public domain - http://unlicense.org/
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.diffplug.osgi.extension.sun.misc
Bundle-Version: 0.0.0
```